# Inserting from Excel sheet to sqlserver?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to insert specific columns from excel into my database on sql server and here's the following code:

```
constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;""", FilePath);
            Econ = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Database='SimDevice_Stocks';Integrated Security= yes;");

            Query = string.Format("Select [ORDER_SUB_TYPE],[ORDER_DATE],[ORDER_STATUS],[SIM_NETWORK_TYPE],[STORE_ID],[ROOT_PRODUCT_ATM_TYPE],[STC_ERP_SIM_ITEM],[STC_SALECO_ITEM_CODE]  FROM [{0}] where ORDER_SUB_TYPE='Change SIM' and ORDER_SUB_TYPE='New'and  ORDER_STATUS = 'Complete' and ROOT_PRODUCT_ATM_TYPE='Prepaid'", "Online_Inventory_Open_Points_re$");
            OleDbCommand Ecom = new OleDbCommand(Query, Econ);
            Econ.Open();   
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query, Econ);
            Econ.Close();
            oda.Fill(ds);
            DataTable Exceldt = ds.Tables[0];
            //creating object of SqlBulkCopy  
            SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
            //assigning Destination table name    
            objbulk.DestinationTableName = "Temp_DailyInventory";
            //Mapping Table column    
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ORDER_SUB_TYPE", "Order_Sub_Type");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Order_Date", "Order_Date");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ORDER_STATUS", "Order_Status");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("SIM_NETWORK_TYPE", "Sim_Network_Type");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("STORE_ID", "Store_ID");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ROOT_PRODUCT_ATM_TYPE", "Root_Product_Atm_Type");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("STC_ERP_SIM_ITEM", "Stc_Erp_Sim_Item");
            objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("STC_SALECO_ITEM_CODE", "Stc_Saleco_Item_Code");

   con.Open();
   objbulk.WriteToServer(Exceldt);
   con.Close();
```

so i've got 2 type of data in my excel sheet column of the Order_Sub_Type it got Change sim and New so i need to enter those 2 records but i'm not able to insert them as you can see in the above query i can either choose one to enter "Change Sim" or "New".

Thanks in advance

Comment: @CodingYoshi any help please

Comment: @marc_s any help?

Comment: I think you have something wrong in your query's where statement. It states: where ORDER_SUB_TYPE='Change SIM' and ORDER_SUB_TYPE='New' ,it should be either one of those or replace the 'and' with 'or'.

Comment: @Christiaan van Bergen i know that buddy but i need to add the two records can i?

Comment: Yes, just change it to: WHERE ( ORDER_SUB_TYPE='Change SIM' OR ORDER_SUB_TYPE='New') and ...etc..

Comment: Thank you buddy it worked :) @ChristiaanvanBergen